# Find the Painted X and Y position (e.g. top left corner) of a Qt QML Text Element

Tags: qt, text, qml, metrics

Related to TextMetrics and this [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d116B.png).

Is there a way to accurately align a rectangle to surround some enclosed text? The reason I would like to get pixel accurate alignment of the rectangle and the text is because I would like to paint the text next to some graphics, for example a plot.

Thanks to the answer below, I've almost got the text and the rectangle aligned, but it is still a few pixels off, and the alignment seems to vary across platforms. Screenshot is from OSX.

```
TextMetrics {
    id: textMetrics
    text: "TextSample72"
    font.pointSize: 72
}
Rectangle {
    width: textMetrics.tightBoundingRect.width
    height: textMetrics.tightBoundingRect.height
    color: "#bbbbdd"
    z: 0
    Text {
        id: textSample72
        text: "TextSample72"
        font.pointSize: 72
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignBottom
        z:1
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextMetrics` only serves to know the width and height of the text since it would not make sense to know the position x and y since it only analyzes the font used.

In the image you can see that there is a vertical displacement of the text, and that displacement is caused by the anchors, in your code you are indicating that it is centered in the rectangle but in addition to it you are also indicating that the upper part coincides with the upper part of the rectangle, if the height of the font does not match the height of the rectangle (as in this case), you are forcing it to stretch by generating an offset in the `y` position of the text.

A possible solution is to set the alignment of the text to `Text.AlignBottom` so there would be no difference between the height of the text and the height of Text, and if you want to move just have to do it in the Rectangle.

```
TextMetrics {
    id: textMetrics
    text: textSample72.text
    font: textSample72.font
}
Rectangle {
    y: 40  // if the rectangle is moved, 
    x: 40  // the text will also move
    width: textMetrics.tightBoundingRect.width
    height: textMetrics.tightBoundingRect.height
    color: "#bbbbdd"
    Text {
        id: textSample72
        text: "TextSample72"
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignBottom
        font.pointSize: 72
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. The two anchor statements (top and vcenter) was a typo. I edited the question. Using your response, I am almost able to get perfect alignment on OSX, but it is still a few pixels off.

Comment: @Colin  in the image that I show I do not see any pixel off.

Comment: @Colin You could show me an image of what you get with my solution.

Comment: yes are you in windows or linux? I have found that the text positioning varies across platforms. I played around with the alignment properties and posted a screenshot from OSX which is the closest I was able to come to perfect alignment. Closer than before, but still a few pixels off.

Comment: @Colin 
I'm in Linux, but I smell like a bug.

Comment: hi again - just checked and in windows, I do see perfect alignment as in your screenshot.

Comment: @Colin Linux and Windows are correct, so it already *sucks* bug

Comment: yes, linux too. Must be related to the platform plugin for osx, or some such. Thanks for the help - should be good enough for now.